# Passing DateTime in api url in c#

Tags: c#, api

I have an api url in the following format;

```
https://MyAPI.com/stuff/pending_since/{{DATE-TIME}}
```

I've tried;

```
var myDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
var stringTask = client.GetStringAsync("https://MyAPI.com/stuff/pending_since/{{myDate}}");
var json = await stringTask;
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

That returns an error. How do I pass the date in the url?
Thanks,
John

Comment: You'll probably want to specify a format for `myDate` rather than just letting .NET use whatever the current thread's culture is to determine the format. [As you can see](https://rextester.com/NEYZO34500), different cultures will have different formats. The default culture an applications starts under depends on the OS settings.

Comment: Also: what is the format the API requires specifically?

Comment: "That returns an error" - when you ask a question about an error, *always* give precise details about the error. What kind of error is it? What's the exact text of the error message?

Comment: Note that the URL you're hitting is *literally* `https://MyAPI.com/stuff/pending_since/{{myDate}}`. You're not using the value of the variable at all. I don't know whether that's because you made a mistake when creating the code for the question, or whether that's actually in the broken code you're running. This is where a [mcve] would really help...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a format which doesn't contain slashes, otherwise it'll mess up the Url, and use `InvariantCulture` when formatting the date.

```
string dateStr = myDate.ToString("s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var stringTask = client.GetStringAsync($"https://MyAPI.com/stuff/pending_since/{dateStr}");
```

where the format specifier `s` is known as the [Sortable date/time pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier).

The date will be formatted as: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` which should be compatible with URLs.

Also, as Hans mentioned, you will probably need to use an interpolated string: `$"https://MyAPI.com/stuff/pending_since/{dateStr}"` in `GetStringAsync` (prepended with `$` and only one set of `{}` braces.

Comment: @JohnFlaherty Could you add the exact error message to the question please?

Comment: You may need to use `$"https://MyAPI.com/stuff/pending_since/{dateStr}"` (note the leading `$` and the single `{ }`)